# UI Fabric-js Pivot control - no link item overflow functionality

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-ui-fabric

I am trying to use the [Pivot](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/blob/master/ghdocs/components/Pivot.md) component from the Office UI Fabric JS library but I have found that it does not have functionality to deal with link items overflow.

The documentation shows the overflow as ellipsis however this does not have any functionality behind it. It is just for presentation.

As anyone modified this component so that it automatically resize and show all the links correctly?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [known issue with the Pivot control](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/issues/61). In order to get it to work, you need to override the `overflow-x: hidden` that is set in the default stylesheet. Adding the following to your page's CSS seems to fix it:

```
.ms-Pivot{
  overflow-x: visible;
}
```

You'll also need to make sure you wire up the JavaScript for Pivot *and* Context Menu. This includes the script to swap the `is-hidden` and `is-open` classes when clicking on the ellipsis.

At the moment there isn't any automatic sizing of tab or automatically moving the overflowed elements into a context menu.

Comment: Thank you @Marc LaFleur. What you said helps. I am currently using `height:auto; overflow-x: auto; white-space: normal;` to let the control overflow onto another line... It does not look very good but haven't got the time to extend the control to work with the ellipses overflow. I might revisit that in the next few weeks. For now, I am going to leave this question open, in case someone has a code snippet to share :)